# how to insert json data in postgres using spring

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

i have a table in **POSTGRES SQL** which has a column of type `JSON(not jsonb its json)`.
now i create a POJO and try to save it using spring JPA REPOSITORY `save` method.

What i tried : 
Now if i send the json as String it fails saying cannot convert CVAR to json and if i send as jsonObject then it fails saying cannot convert BYTEA to json.

I know how to use jsonb but for json i am not sure how do i insert it,one approach i found was to write a insert statement and then type case it instead of directly suing the save method of repository, but as i have many columns in the table i cant pass them all in function and then save it.
now how should i accomplish it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL uses binary mapping internally to store both json and jsonb data type. Below should work for json column type.

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
```

See the sample for postgres [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/)